# What is the meaning of [...] regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex going through the [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) I found the regex `[...]` says `Matches any single character in brackets.`. So I tried

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[...]","[l]"));
```

I also tried escaping brackets

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[...]","\\[l\\]"));
```

But it gives me `false` I expected `true` because `l` is inside brackets.

It would be helpful if anybody clear my doubts.

Comment: The brackets will not be a part of match.If you want to match `[l]` use `\\[l\\]`

Comment: Also: ... expects three characters.

Comment: @Stultuske it does not expect `3` characters........it just says one of them which is same here though

Comment: @vks I tried [your solution](http://ideone.com/r7WtZn) too but it gives me false

Comment: @codegasmer you have to escape the `regex` not the `literal string`.See http://ideone.com/IK80cF

Comment: It says that `[XYZ]` matches `X` or `Y` or `Z`

Comment: @vks . => matches any single character. do remember, we are looking at a TutorialsPoint tutorial here. You know, the page that says (and I quote) "As of December 2008, the latest release of the Java Standard Edition is 6 (J2SE). "
TutorialsPoint (up until a few months ago) kept insisting that using interfaces, you could achieve multiple inheritance in Java. Long story short: just because TutorialsPoint says it's so, doesn't make it so.

Comment: The `...` was supposed to be a placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters that are inside `[` and `]` (called a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) are treated as a set of characters to choose from, except *leading* `^` which negates the result and `-` which means range (if it's between two characters). Examples:

- `[-123]` matches `-`, `1`, `2` or `3`
- `[1-3]` matches a single digit in the range 1 to 3
- `[^1-3]` matches any character *except* any of the digits in the range 1 to 3
- `.` matches *any character*
- `[.]` matches the *dot* `.`

If you want to match the string `[l]` you should change your regex to:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("...", "[l]"));
```

Now it prints `true`.

The regex `[...]` is equivalent to the regexes `\.` and `[.]`.

Comment: @timpietzcker - makes my answers look better :)

Comment: I think *Alan* is right.. The OP knows what `[...]` means.. So, your answer is *more correct* . He should probably look at *regexes in depth* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind The tutorial should use a better placeholder than this one, it's very confusing for newcomers.

Comment: Using `...` as a placeholder is a very common practice.  What the tutorial should do is *explain* it better.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Couldn't agree more. Confusing questions lead to confusing answers:P

Comment: @AlanMoore - Correct. The issue is that the OP is confused

Comment: @AlanMoore Is it a good placeholder even for regexes? I find it confusing a bit. But you're right, the tutorial should explain it better.

Comment: @TheLostMind and MarounMaroun confusion is clear now.I am also following your other java stack threads they are very helpful,you both are great god will surely bless you

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial is a little misleading, it says:

> [...] Matches any single character in brackets.

However what it means is that the regex will match a single character against any of the characters inside the brackets. **The ... means "insert characters you want to match here"**. So you need replace the ... with the characters that you want to match against.

For example, `[AP]M` will match against "AM" and "PM".

If your regex is literally `[...]` then it will match against a literal dot. Note there is no point repeating characters inside the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial is saying:

> Matches any single character in brackets.

It means you replace `...` with a single character, for example `[l]`

These will print true:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[l]","l"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[.]","."));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[.]*","."));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[.]*","......"));
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[.]+","......"));
```

Comment: `[...]` is a valid regex. It *can* be simplified to `[.]`, but it's definitely valid.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I assumed he was trying to say what I said in my (now deleted) comment: that they're not talking about the actual regex `[...]`.  The answer is still a little confusing, though.  I think it's better to get rid of the dots altogether and use realistic examples like the ones in your answer.